# .NET HttpClient sendAsync() Timeout on second request specifically

Tags: asp.net, iis, httpclient

I been working on a proxy-like controller on ASP.NET, it takes URL from incoming request and uses HttpClient to call the URL, then return the file.

This proxy-like controller work like this:

- Works fine when executing one request
- Works fine when executing multiple requests,those responses have content-type of "application/json" and "xml"
- Request Time-out on 2nd request and Task Cancelled when executing 4 requests, those responses have content-type of "image/png". Like following:

---

(These 4 request are being sent to controller almost at the same time).

- Request 1 - start at 0s , finished at 1s
- Request 2 - start at 1s ,Time out and exception throw at 11:00(Time out is 10s), server hangs until timeout
- Request 3 - start at 11s , finished at 12s
- Request 4 - start at 12s , finsihed at 13s

**Please Ignore the POST Situation**

**Controller**

```
public async Task<FileStreamResult> Proxy(string method, string url, string data = "")
{
    myHttpClient client = new myHttpClient();
    Tuple<MemoryStream,string> result = await client.Proxy(this.Request, method, url).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return File(result.Item1,result.Item2); //file stream and file type
}
```

**HttpClient**

```
public class myHttpClient
{
    private static HttpClient _httpClient;
    static myHttpClient()
    {
        if (_httpClient == null) {
            _httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials = true });
            _httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(7);
            Log ocLog = new Log();
            ocLog.Write("init client " + ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit ,false);
        }
    }
    public async Task<Tuple<MemoryStream, string>> Proxy(HttpRequestBase contextRequest, string method, string url)
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
        request.RequestUri = new Uri("http://localhost" + url);
        if (method == "GET")
        {
            request.Method = HttpMethod.Get;
            request.Content = null;
        }
        else if (method == "POST")
        {
            request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
        }

        //copy request header from context.Request
        foreach (string headerName in contextRequest.Headers)
        {
            string[] headerValues = contextRequest.Headers.GetValues(headerName);
            if (!request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation(headerName, headerValues))
            {
                request.Content.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation(headerName, headerValues);
            }
        }

        try
        {
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false))
            {
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var contentBytes = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(contentBytes);
                    return new Tuple<MemoryStream, string>(ms, response.Content.Headers.ContentType.ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

***What have i tried***

1. Checking ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit. It is very large.
2. Use System.net.WebRequest library instead of HttpClient, still the same.

Comment: It sounds like something was locked up when your web application execute async proxy controller. Have you tried to viewed the dump file?

Comment: No, i know nothing about dump file. I just tried another image api for my proxy controller and all request works. However, when the proxy called "http://localhost/otherWebsiteOnIIS/xxxx.fcgi?querystring", it not working for some request.

Comment: The problem seem to be occured when localhost sending request to localhost itself too frequently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved by setting the "Maximum Process Workers" of the application pool to 3. It did the trick